# Unable to connecting POE device with router via a POE injector

Tags: networking, router, power-over-ethernet

I'm having trouble with connecting my POE device with the router.
This is an illustration showing my connectivity:

[image]

In CASE A, I'm trying to power the POE device (a Road-Side-Unit) via a POE injector, and connecting the POE device with the Router using ethernet cable. So I can access the POE device using my PC under the same local area network. However, it cannot work.

The problem is: it seems that the router cannot connect to the POE device. The LAN port light is off. The device has been originally assigned with an IP address, and I disable the DHCP server service of the router. My PC is connected with the router via wifi, and I cannot access the POE device using `ping`, `ssh` or something else.

However, In CASE B, when connecting the POE device directly to my PC, it works.

What might be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Does the PoE device power up? If yes, your problem seems to be the actual data link.

Classically, there are two pinouts for twisted-pair Ethernet ports: MDI for end devices and MDI-X for switches and hubs. Routers used to have MDI ports for a direct connection to a switch. Home routers usually include multiple, switched "LAN" ports, so you would expect MDI-X ports instead.

With the standard cable being straight through, you could only connect unlike devices (MDI to MDI-X). Like devices (two MDI or two MDI-X) used to require a crossover cable to adapt the wiring.

Since the late 1990s, *Auto MDI-X* has become very common, where devices automatically choose the correct pinout. The need for crossover cables has all but vanished and forgotten. However, when neither side of a link implements (still optional!) Auto MDI-X and you connect like devices you still need a crossover cable or adapter.

My guess is that both router and RSU use MDI-X ports without automatic switching and you should try a crossover cable or adapter.